How can I make a screen shader for orthogonal camera in Godot 4?
There is a very old issue explaining that there's problems with it, and I'm having difficulties today:
https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/48202
The standard practice is to:

Have a camera3d
make a MeshInstance3D -> Mesh:Quad as child of the camera (optional)
give it a material -> shader
have the shader code set POSITION and reference screen_texture

Example Shader Code:
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

uniform sampler2D screen_texture: source_color, hint_screen_texture, filter_nearest;

void vertex() {
    POSITION = vec4(VERTEX, 1.0);
    //POSITION = vec4(VERTEX - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0);
}

void fragment() {
    vec3 color = texture(screen_texture, SCREEN_UV).rgb;
    float luminance = 0.299 * color.r + 0.587 * color.g + 0.114 * color.b;
    ALBEDO = vec3(luminance, 0.0, 1.0);
}

The problem is that this only works for regular perspective cameras.  If the projection style is set to orthogonal, it all stops working.
Why?  And how do I fix it?

It turns out the rabbit hole was much deeper than expected.  In a nutshell, post-processing isn't well supported in Godot.
Someone came up with a way though:  https://github.com/godotengine/godot-docs-user-notes/discussions/42#discussioncomment-11318393
It involves 4 separate cameras rendering the same scene multiple ways to isolate each buffer (albedo, normals, roughness, depth, etc).  From there, they can can be mixed back together again.
Godot is working on "the compositioner" which should solve this missing feature.

OLD ANSWER:
POSITION = vec4(VERTEX.xy, 1.0, 1.0);
https://godotengine.org/article/introducing-reverse-z/

When you write to POSITION in Godot, you are bypassing the built-in vertex transformation and writing a clip space position directly. This can be helpful to optimize a vertex shader, or to achieve certain effects (like having a mesh stay fixed in the camera view). Commonly users wrote the following line:
POSITION = vec4(VERTEX, 1.0);
This line is even reproduced in our documentation. It relies on users supplying a QuadMesh with a width and height of 2 to fill the entire screen. The code assumes that:
All vertices of the mesh have a Z-coordinate of 0 (which is true for the QuadMesh), and
A clip space value of 0 corresponds to the near plane.
We have broken assumption 2 by flipping the definition of the near plane and the far plane, so this code no longer works. Instead, users need to write:
POSITION = vec4(VERTEX.xy, 1.0, 1.0);
And that’s it!

